# Writing an Excel formula to determine the exact amount of Volume needed per week to exceed a growing and evolving Volume goal?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to write a Excel math formula which will help me determine how much Volume I need per week compared to Representative A. I want to know exactly how much more I need per week on average in order to catch Representative A. Here is some of the data:

```
Representative A: Goal 710 Volume Current Volume 223
Wk 1 16.47% into goal
Wk 2 31% into goal (+14.92% from Wk 1)

Current trend is 111.5 Volume per week; 15 weeks left; 1672.5+223=1895.5 total Volume or 266.82% over 710 Goal

My Data: Goal 2267 Volume Current Volume 450
Wk 1 11.25% into goal
Wk 2 20% into goal (+8.45% from Wk 1)
Current trend is 225 Volume per week; 15 weeks left; 3375+450=3825 total Volume or 168.74% over 2267 Goal
```

How do I write the formula to determine My Data needing to be at 266.821% in order to exceed Representative A's % Goal? And what would that look like in terms of Volume needed per week? There week to week averages should change as well so I'm at a loss at how to make this fluid.

I have broken down the math manually where for instance I would need +66.77% more per week or 150.231 Volume more (375.231 total per week) to exceed Representative A's 266.821%. At least, I think that math is correct.

Comment: I've little confusion ,,, for Rep A Goal is 710 and WK1 16.47% of 710 =116.94 (Rounded) + Wk2 31% of 710 =220.01 (Rounded) ,, WK1+Wk2= 337.04 and you have written Current Vol 223 !!, Also how you get 1672.5 ,,, !! What I've calculated in 2 Weeks achieved Vol is 337,, and 13 weeks are left so you may go with standard math Vol Remaining 372.96/13 (Wks) ,, you get Vol need per week to achieve the Goal 710,,, plzz correct me if I'm wrong or better share Sample data/Wbook on cloud!!

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ff4ADOwVad__DRe0jmS-sY4QrMV6ANxuzBjh82LECn8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi @Josh Nelson check my post below I've tried to solve the issue,, & believe this is what you were looking for,, plzz post reply whether is working or not !

Answer (score 0):

So you need to exceed the performance he hits and that performance is defined as his results vs. his goal.

You give the datum that he is expected to achieve a "266.821%" performance, or in toher words, 2.66821 times his goal.

So if you take that multiplier and multiply your goal by it, then round up to the next full point, you win.

To complicate things, you have already achieved some performance and that can be subtracted from the goal to leave what needs achieved over the next 15 weeks.

So, if you put his percentage expected in A1, your goal in A2, what you have already completed in A3 and the number of weeks left in A4, the following formula will give you the precise amount needed to tie:

```
=(A2*A1/100-A3)/A4
```

You want to win though, but you don't need to round the above up though that would certainly be valid, just as much as 15 points higher than needed. Instead, you need to instead change it so that the total before dividing is rounded, then divided:

```
=ROUNDUP(A2*A1/100-A3,0)/A4
```

Rounding UP, to exceed his points expected.

In the practical world, you might want to build some fudge into that, exceed the 266.821% by achieving perhaps 267% or whatever might seem indicated. For instance, that'd be a small extra, but if you are in a business in which a "big score" could fall into his lap, you might need to expect that and achieve more, just in case. A chance big score would be VERY hard to overcome, especially at the last moment. You seem to expect working more/harder to have a fairly linear reward, so build on that, aim for the expected plus a big score. You can vacation later. Vacays are good for replacing girlfriends who walk out on you so it can double up the value.

As a man whose wife left him because he "wasn't there" though she surely wouldn't've wanted to lose the house either... I have some relevant expertise here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I apologize in advance my Excel skills aren't that great. Following your formula above I get:

`=roundup(2267*266.82%/100-450,0)/15`

Is that right? 2267 as my Goal, 266.82% Representatives percentage expected, the amount of Volume already completed, 450, and then divide by 15? That got me -26. What did I end up doing wrong here?

Comment: @JoshNelson,,, yes you are correct & is the write way to calculate,,, you may use SOLVER to get 13 month's value to achieve the goal !!

Answer (score 0):

**:Caveat:**

*Below shown method is based on information posted by OP, that is looking for "exact amount of volume needed per week to exceed a growing and evolving volume goal".*

- *Since OP has not shown any method that how to get 13 week's data, therefore I've used SOLVER.*

---

[image]

- Formula in cell

F36: `=CEILING(SUM(F$20:F$34),1)`

F37: `=$F$18-$F$36`

F38: `=ROUND(F36/15,2)`

F39: `=CEILING($F$38*15,1)`

F40: `=F39+F36`

F41: `=ROUND(F$40*100/F$18,2)`

- *Similar formula has been used in Range B36:B41.*

---

[image]

- Formula in cell

F64: `=FLOOR(SUM(F$48:F$62),1)`

F65: `=F$46-F$64`

F66: `=ROUND(F$64/15,2)`

F67: `=CEILING($F$66*15,1)`

F68: `=F$67+F$64`

F69: `=ROUND(F$68*100/F$46,2)`

- *Similar formula has been used in Range B64:B69.*

---

[image]

- Formula in G43:

`=ROUNDUP($F$46*$F$41%/100-$B$64,0)/15`

---

**::Edited::**

*On the basis of data provided by the OP this should be the best possible solution, since the expected result is based on 13 weeks values.*

[image]

- Formula in J50:J62 setting the trend of the sale for next 13 weeks & the used formula is one of the popular practices used by data analysts.

  `=ABS(TREND(J48:J49,I48:I49,I50:I62))`

---

**N.B.**

*You need to adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: I still don't get it. That doesn't appear to my data to >266.821%.

Comment: I'm not looking to get to 200%, I'm looking to get to >266.821%. I need to know in the remaining 15 weeks (17 weeks total) how much more I need to move in order to exceed Representative's A's amount. Obviously Representative A's amount will also change week by week, but we should be able to assume a constant for a goal oriented path, right?

Comment: @JoshNelson ,, if my method is correct then achieving 266.82% is also possible ,, use SOLVER & simply change the expected value for 266.85% is 6050, if in cell F64 you get 6050 then in F69 you get 266.87%,,, hope I'm moving in right direction,,, correct me in case of any confusion or further question .

Comment: @JoshNelson ,, now check the Edited part of my post I've used formula finding values of rest 13 Week,, to calculate further is based of popular practice used by data analysts. Hope this work for you ,, confirm through comments ☺